# IF-ELSE with multiple IFs

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to do a multiple check of some values but I can't get it to work.

```
if DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeNorth'] = 1 then
    ivol[2] := 1;
  else
  if DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeEast'] = 1 then
    ivol[2] := 1;
  end
  else
  if DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeWest'] = 1 then
  ivol[2]:=1;

  end;
```

I want to check if "VolumeNorth" is 1, and then the index ivol[2] is going to be 1, otherwise if East is 1 ivol[2] should be 1, and if this isn't there's a check for West and also so for South (This isn't in the code yet). If none of them are 1 then nothing should happen with ivol[2]. How do I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't quote fake code which will not compile. It seems to annoy people who might otherwise be inclined to help.

Comment: @MartynA What do you mean by fake code? This is very legit but there's something wrong with my IF argument...

Comment: There are number of clues it's a fake. `;` are not allowed before `else` and there's an extra `end` in the code.

Comment: That's more that I'm not that good at programming. I had a couple of different methods I tried which probably ended up with the code I put on here.

Comment: Sorry, all I meant by "fake" is not genuine in the sense of being something which you have actually compiled successfully.  If the problem you're having is that your code won't compile, your q should include the compiler error message and indicate where is occurs.  Often, just noting the error message will tell you exactly what your syntax error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dmitry's answer is right for your scenario. I'm also an advocate of using BEGIN and END with all IF statements, for code clarity. It then helps you understand your program flow better.

```
if DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeNorth'] = 1 then
begin
  ivol[2] := 1;
end
else if DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeEast'] = 1 then
begin
  ivol[2] := 1;
end
else if DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeWest'] = 1 then
begin
  ivol[2]:=1;
end;
```

Comment: Wtf, I'm almost certain that I tried this before but it didn't work. It does now tho, thank you very much! I edited a followup question if you could answer that as well :)

Comment: Well nevermind, I think I found my answer anyway. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, User. If you've found your answer, and it's from one of the responses posted here, then mark that as the *accepted* response. If your solution was different, then please post your solution as an *answer* here so that others can learn, too. But please make sure that your answer really answers the question you asked above.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't use boolean ***or***?

```
if (DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeNorth'] = 1) or
   (DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeEast'] = 1) or
   (DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeWest'] = 1) or
   (DerobModel.HouseProperties.IntValue['VolumeSouth'] = 1) then
  ivol[2] := 1;
```

if ***any*** of volume (North, East, West, South) is `1` set `ivol[2]` to `1`; if none of volumes are equal to 1 nothing is happen (pay attention, there's ***no*** `else` block)

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I need a couple of more checks thats why I didn't want to use the or boolean as I need to check which Volume is 1 :)